# Replace several matches occurrences in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code to change my string colors that comes with tags like (^0, ^1, ^2, ^3, ..., ^9)
I did with php but I confused how I can do same function with JavaScript?

```
$host = "^5MY ^4Team ^2Name ^8Is ^6LOL";

function getColoredName($host){
    $count_rpl = 0;
    $hostname = $host;
    $h2 = str_replace("^1","<div style='color:#FF0000;'>", $hostname, $count_rpl_1);
    $h3 = str_replace("^2","<div style='color:#00FF00;'>", $h2, $count_rpl_2);
    $h4 = str_replace("^3","<div style='color:#FFFF00;'>", $h3, $count_rpl_3);
    $h5 = str_replace("^4","<div style='color:#0000FF;'>", $h4, $count_rpl_4);
    $h6 = str_replace("^5","<div style='color:#00FFFF;'>", $h5, $count_rpl_5);
    $h7 = str_replace("^6","<div style='color:#FF00FF;'>", $h6, $count_rpl_6);
    $h8 = str_replace("^7","<div style='color:#FFFFFF;'>", $h7, $count_rpl_7);
    $h9 = str_replace("^0","<div style='color:#000000;'>", $h8, $count_rpl_8);
    $final = str_replace("^8","<div style='color:#000000;'>", $h9, $count_rpl_9);
    $count = $count_rpl_1 + $count_rpl_2 + $count_rpl_3 + $count_rpl_4 + $count_rpl_5 + $count_rpl_6 + $count_rpl_7 + $count_rpl_8 + $count_rpl_9;
    $final = $final . str_repeat("</div>", $count);
    return $final;
}
```

How I do same function in JavaScript if possible someone make same one for me?

```
<script>
function getColoredName(input) {
    if (input != undefined)

    ....

}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you [search](https://www.google.com/#q=javascript+replace+string) before you asked the question? What specifically are you having problems with? Maybe reading a [JavaScript tutorial](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) would be a good first step? *"if possible someone make same one for me"* That's not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Yes i just found for single text replace but in my case i have to multiple cuz i posted my problems i will thankful if you can help me.

Comment: *"i just found fore single text replace but in my case i have to multiple"* Can you elaborate on that? Is the problem with replacing multiple different strings (`^1`, `^2`, etc)  or multiple occurrences of the same string (e.g. `^1` occurs multiple times in the string). If it's the former, you just do the same thing you do in PHP: Call the replacement procedure (`str_replace` in PHP) multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.replace()` should be fun

```js
var text = "^5MY ^4Team ^2Name ^8Is ^6LOL but most of all ^999StackOverflow rules!!";

var sym2clr = {
  "^0": "#000",
  "^1": "#f00",
  "^2": "#0f0",
  "^3": "#ff0",
  "^4": "#00f",
  "^5": "#0ff",
  "^6": "#f0f",
  "^7": "#fff",
  "^8": "#000",
  "^999": "#f48024"
};

var html = text.replace(/(\^\d+)([^\^\s]+)/g, function(_1, $2, $3){
  return "<span style='color:"+ sym2clr[$2] +"'>"+ $3 +"</span>";
});

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

If you want it to account only for a single number use `d` instead of `d+`

Feel free to improve on the above regex: https://regex101.com/r/sD9vW1/1

Answer (score 0):

[`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

The first arg is a pattern or substring to match in the string you call it on. Check out the docs for more advanced usage.